# Concepts for page path in JSP and servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

What is the difference between these two?

**In JSP:**

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

and how to achieve same results if coded without Expression Language and in a servlet?

**In servlet:**

```
request.getServletPath()
```

and how to achieve same results if coded in JSP?

Comment: Seems to be the difference between [this API call](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()) and [this API call](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath()) to me...

Comment: I need to grasp detail of its implications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**${pageContext.request.contextPath}  :** Returns the portion of the request URI that indicates the context of the request. In fact, it is identical to `request.getContextPath()`, since `${pageContext.request}` refers to the `HttpServletRequest` of the current request.

For example:

`http://localhost:80/myapplication/path/servlet`

- `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` returns `/myapplication`
- `request.getServletPath()` Returns the part of this request's URL that calls the servlet, e.g. `/path/servlet`
- `${pageContext.request.servletPath}` returns `/path/servlet`

Comment: Nice. whats the equivalent to request.getServletPath()  in expression language or JSTL

Comment: "${pageContext.request.servletPath} returns /path/servlet" - nope! It will return path where your jsp page is, for example, /WEB-INF/view/home.jsp

Answer (score 2):

As an answer to the second part of your question:

> `request.getServletPath()`and how to achieve same results if coded in
>   a JSP using Expression Language?

---

Here the **equivalent** of `request.getServletPath()`using Expression Language:

`${pageContext.request.servletPath}`

If you want to use other ServletRequest/HttpServletRequest  methods by means of the Expression Language, just use `${pageContext.request.method}`, where *method* is one of the appropriate methods.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a view handled by a JSP, then `${pageContext.request.servletPath}` returned the path of the jsp, and not the servlet path from the `web.xml`.

To get that I used: `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']}`